# Trying to change subnet of "static only" net-adapters from list of computer hostnames. Script runs but no change in subnet mask

Tags: powershell, ip, script, network-adapter, ipv4

I need to change the subnet mask of several machines at once from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0.

The goal is for the script to only do this on net-adapters that have static ipv4 addresses, and for it to change only the subnet mask, leaving the pre-assigned ipv4 IP address unaffected.

The script runs and returns no errors, but when i look at the adapters on the test target machines the subnet mask remains unchanged. Can anyone point out where i might be going wrong in the script?

```
#Defining Variables
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\computers.txt" 
$SubnetMask = "255.255.0.0" 
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"
$Computers

#Loop Through Hostnames 
foreach ($Computer in $Computers) { 
    #Creating a PSSession 
    $PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer 

    #Getting Network Adapters 
    Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
        $NetAdapters = Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceAlias -ne "Wi-Fi"} 
    }

    #Loop Through Network Adapters
    foreach ($NetAdapter in $NetAdapters) {
        #Changing Subnet Mask
        Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias $NetAdapter.InterfaceAlias -PrefixLength 16 -ComputerName $Computer -SubnetMask $SubnetMask 
    }

    #Closing PSSession
    Remove-PSSession -Session $PSSession 
}
```

Comment: Just change the set-netipaddress line to `Set-NetIPAddress -PrefixLength 16` Having it as 24 makes the mask 255.255.255.0 which may be where it is conflicting since you are also passing in -subnetmask 255.255.0.0

Comment: Hi Nazard, thanks for pointing that out! It's a red herring though. I accidentally pasted the version of it when i switched back to 24 for test. I've now amended that in the question post. Indeed it's 16 but sadly it still makes no change to any of the physical or virtual adapters on the machine. :(